# Error cleaning the project

Tags: android, project, beta

I have just switched from Android studio 3 Canary 6 to Android Studio 3 Beta 2. I cleaned the project but I have an error. Who can help me?

edit :    FIXED

I added "google(), jcenter" to Project Structure>Project>Google Plugin Repositories where, I don't know why, the field was empty[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your Android Gradle plugin version to:

```
dependencies {

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you fo the help. I have just fixed it . I added "google(), jcenter" to Project Structure>Project>Google Plugin Repositories where, I don't know why, the field was empty. Thank you again